# Facebook login review: submit test version or production version?

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login

I am working on an iOS app that pulls wall posts from a Facebook user's wall.

This requires "user_status" permission when user is logging in.

What I noticed during development is:

A) If I try to login using a test user on the "test version" of the app, I will not see any warnings on the login permission dialog. Once the test user is logged in with user_status permission, the app can pull posts from the test user's wall correctly.

B) If I try to login using a test user on the "production version" of the app, I will see a warning on the login permission dialog that says "The following permissions have not been approved and are not being shown to people using your app...". If I ignore the warning and proceed to login, the app will NOT be able to pull posts from the test user's wall.

So how to get Facebook to review this permission?

1) My first attempt is to submit the "production version" of the app, I thought when the reviewer review the app, they will temporary approve the permissions for the app so that they could experience what happen when the permission is approved. But what happen is that, the reviewer said that they tried logged in but couldn't see posts from the user's wall! It sounded as if the user_status is still not approved when they are reviewing it.

2) My second attempt is to submit the "test version" of the app. And providing the test users credentials that I have tried myself. To my horror, the reviewer again complaint that they couldn't see any posts being pulled from the wall. This is completely different from what I experience on my machine using the same build, same test users.

What could be the reason? Am I doing it right? Should I submit the test version or the production version of the app? The clue left by the reviewer is that:

"***Even before permission approval, you can configure your app so that test users can grant permission to test the app. I did not see the permission prompt while logging in your app, and this could be the reason.***"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

You definitely want to submit "test" version of the app, with the "test users" you have created.

After being rejected by one reviewer, I resubmitted the exact same build, but now with a youtube video showing all the steps that the reviewer should do, finally, they approved!

Comment: How do you exactly submit a test version? Doesn't that require that you know the UDID of the reviewers device so that they can install an ad hoc build of your app? I thought the only other way for a stranger to install your app is to go through the App Store, which is your production version.

Answer (score 1):

when submitting your app permissions and actions for review, you have to submit the real environment, so the reviewer sees what is actually going on, how you use the permission, how this enhances the user experience.

Provide screen captures and a very simple step-by-step procedure so the reviewer can reproduce your action. 
The reviewer uses your own test user to reproduce the action, so the warning you see doesn't apply.
Bear in mind that the reviewer is an intern (to my horror, because interns should make different experiences, but that's another topic), at least as far as one can see from the access logs, so they may or may not have programming knowledge.

For sure, you have to suppose they don't, as the documentation in the control panel, when you submit the app, explicitly says not to use jargon, or technical things.